# How to use use reference resource function inside if statement

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to send private ips using reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 0)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress to custome extension based on number of vms created if number of vm are 3.then 3 private ips should pass to custome extension and if number of vm are 5.then 5 private ips should pass to custome extension.I defined two extensions but its looking for depencies.

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[equals(variables('numberOfVM'), 3)]",
      "name": "config-app-3",
      "type": "extensions",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 0))]",
          "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 1))]",
          "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 2))]"
       ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "config-app"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh /home/centos/install_apache.sh \',' ','--ip-address \' ,reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 0)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ', reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 1)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ', reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 2)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress)]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[equals(variables('numberOfVM'), 5)]",
      "name": "config-app-5",
      "type": "extensions",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
         "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 0))]",
         "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 1))]",
         "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 2))]",
         "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 3))]",
         "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 4))]",
       ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "config-app"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh /home/centos/install_apache.sh \',' ','--ip-address \' , reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 0)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ', reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 1)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ', reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 2)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ', reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 3)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress,' ', reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 4)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress)]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I am getting below error while deploying template. 'The template reference 'vm-nic-3' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'. so that i trying to define one custome extension which will  handle both condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if()` function to gate them:

```
if(equals(variables('numberOfVM'), 5), reference(concat(variables('nicName'), 3)).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress, '')
```

and you need to repeat this for all the occurrences of reference function

Comment: how can i repeat this reference in this in if condition ? that is my issue

Comment: copy\paste it. you cant iterate it really

Comment: it doesnt, if function only evaluates the "working" path, so if you do something like if(bool, exists, doesntexist) and bool equals to true, it wont error out, because its only checking the true value which exists

Comment: this means only 2 things: you either have a problem elsewhere or did a mistake

Comment: 'The resource '/subscriptions/suscription_id/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/vi
rtualMachines/vm-3/extensions/config-app-3vm' at line '0' and 
column '0' doesn't depend on parent resource '/subscriptions/suscription_id/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-3'. Please add dependency explicitly using the 'dependsOn' syntax.

Comment: yeah, this is something completely different, not related to this, you can just add that dependency (error really tells you what to do here)